# Sortable linked list of objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sorting, linked-list

For a school lab I have to make a linked list of messages and then sort those messages by priority, with "High" priority being pulled out first, then medium, then low.  I've been trying to figure this out for days and I can't wrap my mind around the sorting.  I've been trying to get it to sort without adding anything other than a head and a size field in my ListofMessages class but all I seem to do is add garbage code.  I wanted to figure this out  myself but right now I'm stumped.

Here's what I have so far. Hopefully you can make sense of it:

```
class ListOfMessages
{
    private int m_nSize;
    public Message m_cListStart;
    //public Message m_cNextItem;
    public Message m_cLastItem;

    public ListOfMessages()
    {
        m_nSize = 0;
        m_cListStart = null;
        //m_cNextItem = null;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return m_nSize; }
    }       

    public string Display(Message cMessage)
    {
        return "Message: " + cMessage.m_strMessage + "\nPriority: " + cMessage.m_strPriority;
    }

    //list additions
    public int Add(Message newMessage)
    {
        Message nextMessage = new Message();
        //inserts objects at the end of the list
        if (m_nSize == 0)
        {
            m_cListStart = newMessage;
                //m_cLastItem = newMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            Message CurrentMessage = m_cListStart;

            if (newMessage.m_strPriority == "High")
            {

                    if (m_cListStart.m_strPriority != "High")
                    {
                        //Make the object at the start of the list point to itself
                        CurrentMessage.m_cNext = m_cListStart;
                        //Replace the object at the start of the list with the new message
                        m_cListStart = newMessage;

                    }
                else
                {
                    Message LastMessage = null;

                    for (int iii = 0; iii < m_nSize; iii++)//(newmessage.m_strpriority == iii.m_strpriority)
                    //&& (iii.m_cnext == null);)
                    {
                        if (m_cListStart.m_strPriority != "High")
                        {
                            nextMessage = newMessage;
                            nextMessage.m_cNext =
                            CurrentMessage = nextMessage;
                            //LastMessage.m_cNext = CurrentMessage;
                        }
                        LastMessage = CurrentMessage;

                        if (m_cListStart.m_cNext != null)
                            m_cListStart = m_cListStart.m_cNext;
                    }
                }
                //iii = iii.m_cnext;
            }
                    // for (int iii = m_cListStart; ; iii = iii.m_cNext)//(newMessage.m_strPriority == iii.m_strPriority)
                    //    //&& (iii.m_cNext == null);)
                    //{
                    //    //Message lastMessage = iii;
                    //    if (iii.m_strPriority != iii.m_strPriority)
                    //    {
                    //        //iii.m_cNext = newMessage;
                    //        newMessage.m_cNext = iii.m_cNext;
                    //        iii.m_cNext = newMessage;
                    //    }


                    //m_cLastItem.m_cNext = newMessage;
        }
            //m_cLastItem = newMessage;
            return m_nSize++;
    }

    public Message Pop()
    {
        //Message Current = m_cListStart;
        //if the object at the start of the list has another object after it, make that object the start of the list
        //and decrease the size by 1 after popping an object off if there is more than 1 object after the start of the list
        if (m_cListStart.m_cNext != null)
        {
            m_cListStart = m_cListStart.m_cNext;
        }
        if (m_nSize > 0)
            m_nSize--;
        else
            m_cListStart = null;
        return m_cListStart;
        //if (m_cListStart.m_cNext != null)
        //    m_cListStart = m_cListStart.m_cNext;
        //if (m_nSize > 1)
        //    m_nSize--;
        //return m_cListStart;
    }
```

My pop function to retrieve the messages might need some refining but most of the work right now lies in the Add function.  I'm really just stumbling through the dark there.

Does anyone know of a simple way of doing what I'm asking?

Comment: I'll toss up my garbled code for you.

Comment: you will torture yourself with that code, first try to understand how linked list work and look at some code samples.

Comment: Another thing you should consider is whether the list will be mostly used for inserting elements, then a single sort, then removing elements. Or if inserting and removing will be intermixed.  If it will be intermixed, you could just maintain the list sorted by inserting elements by their sort order.  Would also save you from having to implement sorting since your list will always be sorted.

Comment: why everyone is trying avoid sorting? what s wrong with sorting? you just wanna hack it and get it working? let him learn.

Comment: @user177883, sorting is (relatively) slow. If time complexity matters (and it seems it does here) and you can solve something in linear time, that solution is much better than sorting.

Comment: sorting is slow, compared to your solution below, and luckily, you dont have space constrained. But there are cases in which have limited space. such as what if you have 5 criteria of an object that you need to sort by. then you cant use extra memory. that s the trade off.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you write a custom linked list as follows:

```
class Node<T> : IComparable<T>
{
   public int Priority {set;get;}
   public T Data {set;get;}
   public Node<T> Next {set;get;}
   public Node<T> Previous {set;get;}

   // you need to implement IComparable here for sorting.
}
```

This is your node definitions. Now We need to implement a LinkedList Class.

Your linked list class can be doubly linked list, since you dont have any specs on it. and it would be easier with doubly linked list.

Here is the definition:

```
class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T: IComparable
{
    public Node<T> Head {set;get;}
    public Node<T> Tail {set;get;}

    // set of constructors
    //.....

    public void Insert(Node<T> node)
    {
       // you can do recursive or iterative impl. very easy.
    }

    // other public methods such as remove, insertAfter, insert before, insert last etc.

    public void Sort()
    {
       // easiest solution is to use insertion sort based on priority.
    }

}
```

If you can get away by creating extra memory, ie: another linked list. insertion sort would be fine. For this purpose you need to implement insert after functionality as well.

I have a [LinkedList](http://www.firatatagun.com/circular-doubly-linked-list-via-c/2011/05/21/) implementation, you can check it out. You just need to implement sorting based on priority, you can use bubble sort, insertion sort, or merge sort.

Also, you might want to look at Heap which you can use to implement a priority Queue, it serves the purpose. I have a [Heap Data Structure](http://www.firatatagun.com/minheap-implementation-via-c/2011/07/01/) Implementation, you can check it out.

Comment: I've never really done anything like that. Could you give me more detail or a link that helps explains what you're referring to?

Comment: Our teacher hasn't taught us anything about what you're mentioning :(

Comment: @Greener, What the code above does, is create a `Node` object that extends `IComparable`. A node is basically your link, in the linked list, which points to the previous and the next node. Your list class would then arrange these nodes based on whatever priority you set for it. The best solution I can come up with for this particular scenario would be to create a generic linked list, and then insert and remove elements based on priority. To learn more on how to do that, search for Linked List implementations. That way you wouldn't even need an external sorting mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to have *three* singly-linked lists, one for each priority.

When you add, you add to the end of the correct list. When you remove, you first try to remove from the highest priority list. If that is empty, try the middle one. If even that is empty, use the lowest list.

If you have constant number of priorities, the time complexities are O(1) in both cases.

Comment: what if there are 10 priorities? or N priorities?

Comment: @user177883, the question specifically says there are three priorities. If there is N priorities, you can still use this solution, but it won't be O(1) anymore.

Comment: @user177883: When your program needs to handle 10 or N priorities you can implement that requirement.  Programmers tend to be horrible at predicting how their code will be used in the future.

Comment: @svick your solution would be easiest way to go then, if he is allowed for that.